# How to trigger a function inside a directive associated with angular6 form

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

Hi Is there any way to call a function inside a directive when the form gets pristine. That is I need to add a CSS class to tab header when form get pristine

```
<form [formGroup]="awayForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" awayConfirm [cancelClicked]="cancelClick">
</form>
```

This is my form I had an awayConfirm directive inside my form. This directive just indicates that the form is dirty inside a tab (just add CSS class indication). Now I need to remove the class when form becomes pristine

```
    export class AwayConfirmCheckComponent implements OnInit {  
      ......
     onSubmit(){
        this.awayForm.markAsPristine()
     }
    }
```

When markAsPristine is called I need to trigger a function inside awayConfirm directive.

Comment: Why not use `[ngClass]` and then using `awayForm.pristine` to assign the class?

Comment: Can I watch awayForm.pristine, because the div to be modified is in another component.

Comment: Does that component have a relationship with this component where the form is present? If yes, then you can use an `Output` property. If no, then you can use a shared service to let the other component know when the form was set to pristine. Give me a StackBlitz sample to work with so that I could show you how.

Comment: No component has no relationship to each other. So I need to use a shared service. But is there any way to subscribe or watch whether the form is pristine or not and call the service.

Comment: I would create a `BehaviorSubject<boolean>` in the shared service. I'll then call the `next` method on it and pass it `true` when I set this form to `pristine`. I would also `subscribe` to this `BehaviorSubject` in the other component. Once the `next` method is called, I'll be able to get notified in the other component about it.

Comment: Could you please put this to answer section

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180172/discussion-between-siddajmera-and-anuj-k-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no relationship between the two components, you can pass data between them using a Shared Service.

I would create a `BehaviorSubject<boolean>` in the shared service. I'll then call the `next` method on it and pass it `true` when I set this `form` to `pristine`. I would also `subscribe` to this `BehaviorSubject` in the other component. Once the `next` method is called, I'll be able to get notified in the other component about it.

In shared service:

```
formPristinenessChanged: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);
```

In Component with Form:

```
export class AwayConfirmCheckComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private service: SharedService) {}
  ......
  onSubmit() {
    this.awayForm.markAsPristine();
    this.service.formPristinenessChanged.next(true);
  }
}
```

In other component:

```
constructor(private service: SharedService) {}

this.service.formPristinenessChanged.subscribe(pristine => {
    if(pristine) // formWasSetToPristine
});
```